# Preprocessor to count number of strings in file

Tags: c++, c

I wanted to have a macro (or anything else that works) that can go through the C/C++ file, and count the number of occurrences of a specific string (in the physical C/C++ file).

```
#define numInFile(str) [???]

int main() {
    printf("blahblah");
    printf("You've used printf %d times", numinFile ("printf") - 2); //-2 account for this call
    return 0;
}
```

**Edit:** Question was originally specific to using this functionality for exit calls. It is now generalize for any use.

Comment: This is neither C, nor C++.

Comment: If you are open to using a shell, you can use `grep "quit(300" *.c | wc`.  The first number returned will equal the number of matches.  Use `egrep` if you need regular expressions.

Comment: I cant use grep. I want a preprocessor directive, to count, and USE that number IN the c/c++ file. Its not a dup, because that question only prints it, doesnt use it.

Comment: I see. I IMHO can't imagine a legitimate use case.

Comment: Visual C++ has a non-standard `__COUNTER__` macro that you can use to generate unique values. In standard C++ you can do it within a single file by using the `__LINE__` macro. Visual C++ used to have a problem with `__LINE__`, generating some rubbish text, when the option for "edit and continue debugging" was used; that problem may be there still.

Comment: Let the number of "quit(300" strings in the file be 20. Then all of the lines would call "exit (300 + 20)". They would not be unique.

Comment: I thought it would go through, count 1 instance, replace with 1, continue to instance 2 replace with 2,...

Comment: If you want to have unique values as an error indicator, then either use exceptions in C++ or documented error codes with a determined value, for Christ sake. This whole "let me just count my error() ussage" is bad style at it's best.

Comment: The idea to split them into classes, 300 replaced by MALLOC_ERROR, etc. So I can have unique taylored responses. But as to which actual allocation failed, I dont need to spend time documenting that, because it doesnt provide anything more than just a line number. I have lots of memory allocations (and obviously other thing). For me to micro manage, and make sure not number is used twice, or shift all the numbers if I add a function inbetween is a big waste. Printing the line number I think is better than what i was looking for. Is it still a bad idea? Whats the alternative?

Comment: That's one of the reason why exceptions are so handy in C++: new (C++ way of malloc, one could say) would throw an exception 'allocation failure', and if nobody captures it, many runtime environments would say :"Hey bad allocation at ...". For the C world @a3f s answer is the best.

Comment: Generalized the question as per most comments.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly, you want to have unique error codes, that you can trace back to the line where the error happened?

I will address that [Y question instead of your X one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem):

You can use [`__LINE__`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/preprocessor/replace). `__LINE__` expands to an integer constant of the current line number. You could `#define` quit as:

```
#define quit(code) (quit)(__LINE__+(code))
void (quit)(code) { // seperate func in case you want to do more
    exit(code);
}
```

Keep in mind though that the exit code of a process is not the best way to encode such information. On POSIX, only the lower 8 bit of an exit code are guaranteed to be available. But as you already use 300 as base value, I assume you are on Windows or some other system where this isn't a concern.

For debugging purposes, alternatively consider writing to `stderr`, when an error happens (maybe with a command line flag).

If `exit` was just an example, and you intend to use it inside your application, you could save `__LINE__` and `__FILE__` in global (or `_Thread_local`) variables on error and store only the exit reason in the error code.

---

Regarding your X question, the preprocessor doesn't do such stuff. You will have to offload such tasks to a shell/perl/whatever script that your build script can call.

Comment: (Exit was just an example) Related to xy: Thanks for the link, I had a question (uniqe codes) came up with an answer (counting) and so I asked the second (more recent one) instead of the actualy one!

Comment: I would try to be portable and only use `EXIT_FAILURE` and `EXIT_SUCCESS` anything more, should either be expressed by an exception or `stderr` output.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing built-in to do this. It would be possible to hook something up to your build system to generate a header file with the relevant counts and use a macro to pull the right value from that header file.

However, based on the fact that various unix systems put limits on the range of exit values (the linux machine I am looking at will only use the lowest 8 bits, meaning that `exit(256)` will be identical to `exit(0)`) you probably actually don't want to do this in the first place, you'd be better off using a logging macro that emits the name of the compilation unit, the line where it was expanded and then uses `exit(EXIT_FAILURE)`.